# Transaction cannot be rolled back because it has been finished with state: commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

```js
let transaction
try{
    transaction = await ctx.app.model.transaction();
    const newPageResult = await pageService.add(addPageResult, { transaction });
    await transaction.commit();
    throw new Error("do rollback")

}catch(){
   transaction.rollback()
}
```

```
2021-04-28 17:02:53,801 ERROR 14904 [-/127.0.0.1/-/75306ms POST /page/copyPage] nodejs.Error: Transaction cannot be rolled back because it has been finished with state: commit
    at Transaction.rollback (/Users/my/work/node_modules/sequelize/lib/transaction.js:85:35)
    at PageController.copyPage (/Users/my/work/app/controller/pageController.ts:418:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have read source code, If `await transcation.commit()`, `this.finished` must be **"commit"**

So If want to rollback must throw error... Here is the source code

[image]

[image]

Comment: That `await` successfully commits the transaction, and _then_  you throw an error, which redirects you to the `catch` clause, where you try to rollback a transaction that has been successfully commited... Why...? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Cerbrus  After creating data, there are some logic todo. They depend on third system, so if third system throw error, I should rollback created data. Very thanks for you reply

Comment: Afaik, you can't rollback a committed tranaction...